# accessing Dynamic Regions in gemfire cache

Tags: caching, distributed-caching, gemfire

i dynamically create some regions using  dynamic region factory in a gemfire distributed cache system.
Although  the regions exist in the server cache ( they appear when i print the existing regions) if i try to get them using the subRegion method i get a null pointer in return.

Are Dynamic Regions accessed other way, or what could the problem be?

Comment: Could you post your server cache.xml and the code that triggers the NPE?

Comment: Well, i figured out what was the problem. I was trying to access the regions from C++ client ( that i forgot to mention) and apparently that was not syncronized with the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a FunctionAdapter to create the region (or check if the region exists) on the server first , then, create a mirrored version (a local region with the same path) on the c++ client